# Converting a hex string into the correct form for the bytes function

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, type-conversion

I am getting two hex string from a function:

```
def getHex(hexIn):
    return hex(hexIn >> 8), hex(hexIn & 0xFF)
```

Then I want to do this:

```
Hi, Lo = getHex(14290)
Cmd = bytes([0x66, 0x44, 0xA6, Hi, Lo])
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can I convert this to a form like `0x66`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you report indicates that you are using python3.

Replace:

```
Cmd = bytes([0x66, 0x44, 0xA6, Hi, Lo])
```

With:

```
Cmd = bytes([0x66, 0x44, 0xA6, int(Hi, 16), int(Lo, 16)])
```

The `hex` function that is used in `getHex` returns strings.  `bytes` wants a list of integers.  The solution is to convert the strings to integers using `int`.

Comment: thank you. that worked well. I was trying int(Hi) before.

I am using [https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html] to learn but do you know of any place where I can look "in reverse" (so put a functionality and get the function rather than the other way around)?

Comment: For reverse lookups, I use google.  For example, `python3 convert hex to decimal` will yield the `int(x, 16)` solution.